# Sending request.get with a specified value for a drop down table

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need to use requests.get for the weblink:

https://www.investing.com/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd-historical-data

The default is bitfinex but I need the page for Kraken which can be chosen from a drop down. I include the html code below. I don't see an option value to select and then pass as a data parameter so how do I set the value of this drop down using the requests.get please?

```
<div class="clear"></div><div class="exchangeDropdownContainer             float_lang_base_1 instDropDown" id="DropDownContainer">
<a id="DropdownBtn" class="newBtnDropdown inlineblock ">
                <span class="ceFlags bitcoin">&nbsp;</span>
            <i class="btnTextDropDwn arial_12 bold">Bitfinex</i>
                <i class="bottunImageDoubleArrow buttonWhiteImageDownArrow">&nbsp;</i>
        </a>
        <table class="genTbl closedTbl exchangeDropdownTbl displayNone" id="DropdownSiblingsTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="center">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="left">Symbol</th>
            <th class="left">Exchange</th>
            <th class="center">Currency</th>
            <th class="left">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                        <tr data-href="/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd-historical-data" class="selected">
                <td class="center"><i class="ceFlags bitcoin">&nbsp;</i></td>
                <td class="left bold"><a href="/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd-historical-data">BTC/USD</a></td>
                <td class="left">Bitfinex</td>
                <td class="center">USD</td>
                <td class="left lightgrayFont bold">Real-time</td>
            </tr>
                        <tr data-href="/indices/investing.com-btc-usd-historical-data" >
                <td class="center"><i class="ceFlags bitcoin">&nbsp;</i></td>
                <td class="left bold"><a href="/indices/investing.com-btc-usd-historical-data">BTC/USD</a></td>
                <td class="left">Investing.com</td>
                <td class="center">USD</td>
                <td class="left lightgrayFont bold">Real-time</td>
            </tr>
                        <tr data-href="/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd-historical-data?cid=53082" >
                <td class="center"><i class="ceFlags bitcoin">&nbsp;</i></td>
                <td class="left bold"><a href="/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd-historical-data?cid=53082">BTC/USD</a></td>
                <td class="left">OKCoin</td>
                <td class="center">USD</td>
                <td class="left lightgrayFont bold">Real-time</td>
            </tr>
                        <tr data-href="/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd-historical-data?cid=1010780" >
                <td class="center"><i class="ceFlags bitcoin">&nbsp;</i></td>
                <td class="left bold"><a href="/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd-historical-data?cid=1010780">BTC/USD</a></td>
                <td class="left">Poloniex</td>
                <td class="center">USD</td>
                <td class="left lightgrayFont bold">Real-time</td>
            </tr>
                        <tr data-href="/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd-historical-data?cid=1010796" >
                <td class="center"><i class="ceFlags bitcoin">&nbsp;</i></td>
                <td class="left bold"><a href="/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd-historical-data?cid=1010796">BTC/USD</a></td>
                <td class="left">GDAX</td>
                <td class="center">USD</td>
                <td class="left lightgrayFont bold">Real-time</td>
            </tr>
                        <tr data-href="/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd-historical-data?cid=53073" >
                <td class="center"><i class="ceFlags bitcoin">&nbsp;</i></td>
                <td class="left bold"><a href="/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd-historical-data?cid=53073">BTC/USD</a></td>
                <td class="left">ANX</td>
                <td class="center">USD</td>
                <td class="left lightgrayFont bold">Real-time</td>
            </tr>
                        <tr data-href="/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd-historical-data?cid=49799" >
                <td class="center"><i class="ceFlags bitcoin">&nbsp;</i></td>
                <td class="left bold"><a href="/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd-historical-data?cid=49799">BTC/USD</a></td>
                <td class="left">Kraken</td>
                <td class="center">USD</td>
                <td class="left lightgrayFont bold">Real-time</td>
            </tr>
```

I need to set the drop down table to the Kraken option

Answer (score 0):

Pass the request to the following url

https://www.investing.com/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd-historical-data?cid=49799

Just change the dropdown in the base url page and you can see that the cid parameter is added to it. While doing web scraping it is important to play around with the site you are about to scrape.

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.' }
url="https://www.investing.com/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd-historical-data?cid=49799"
response=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Cheers - I saw that and tried it but I wondered if there was a more elegant way